# How to combine :not Selector with > Selector?

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list that looks something like this, but more extensive:

```
<ul>
   <li class="cat-item-15">Parent Category 2</li>
   <li class="cat-item-16">Parent Category 2</li>
   <li class="cat-item-17">Parent Category 3
        <ul class="children">
          <li>Child Category 1</li>
          <li>Child Category 2</li>
          <li>Child Category 3</li>
        </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want to hide every `li` except of the Child Categories with `display: none`. My idea was to use the `:not` Selector and exclude all Child Categories. I am able to address the Child Categories with `ul.children > li` but how do I combine this with the `:not` Selector?

Any ideas?

Comment: Your child ul should be wrapped in tag li.

Comment: What is the end result ?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov in fact, it is. I just made a mistake while providing the code sample.

Comment: @ZohirSalak I have an already built menu with all product categories that exist and now I have to reduce it to just the subcategories, but in CSS.

Comment: You want only  the sub `<ul>` to be visible ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak exactly, but I have no access to the HTML code. So it has to be solved in CSS.

Comment: If the  `<li>` that holds the sub `<ul>` is always the last one that would be easy, otherwise i don't this it can be done, because you're trying to select an element based on it's children which can't be done for now.

Comment: You wrote: "I want to hide every li except of the Child Categories with `display: none`". But you didn't post any CSS, and from your HTML code it can't be seen *which* elements have `display: none`. So I think you need to add some more code and/or explanation to your question...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to do this dynamically without adding a class name to the parent li that contains the ul.children. There is a [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class which would accomplish this but it does not work in [most browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas()).

As an alternative, you can dynamically apply a unique class to the parent items that contain a ul.children list using javascript. This will allow you to then target the parent list items with the new class. I have attached a working example using JS.

```js
var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');

menuItems.forEach(menuItem => {
    var submenu = menuItem.querySelectorAll('.children');

    if (submenu.length) {
        menuItem.classList.add('has-sub-menu');
    }
});
```

```css
ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li.has-sub-menu {
   display: block;
}

ul.children li {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="cat-item-15">Parent Category 2</li>
   <li class="cat-item-16">Parent Category 2</li>
   <li class="cat-item-17">Parent Category 3
        <ul class="children">
          <li>Child Category 1</li>
          <li>Child Category 2</li>
          <li>Child Category 3</li>
        </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="cat-item-17">Parent Category 4</li>
   <li class="cat-item-17">Parent Category 5
        <ul class="children">
          <li>Child Category 1</li>
          <li>Child Category 2</li>
          <li>Child Category 3</li>
        </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If tag `<li>` containing tag `<ul>` is **not dynamic**, then it is possible to use pseudo-class `:nth-child()`, indicating the ordinal number, with the joint use of pseudo-class `:not()`, excluding the parent tag `<ul>`.

```css
ul:not(.children) > :not(li:nth-child(3)) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="cat-item-15">Parent Category 1</li>
    <li class="cat-item-16">Parent Category 2</li>
    <li class="cat-item-17">Parent Category 3
        <ul class="children">
            <li>Child Category 1</li>
            <li>Child Category 2</li>
            <li>Child Category 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For the **rest** of the `<li>` tags containing the `<ul>` tag, you can also use the pseudo-class `:nth-child()`, inside the `:not()` pseudo-class.

```css
ul:not(.children) > :not(li:nth-child(3), li:nth-child(7)) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="cat-item-15">Parent Category 1</li>
    <li class="cat-item-16">Parent Category 2</li>
    <li class="cat-item-17">Parent Category 3
        <ul class="children">
            <li>Child Category 1</li>
            <li>Child Category 2</li>
            <li>Child Category 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item-18">Parent Category 4</li>
    <li class="cat-item-19">Parent Category 5</li>
    <li class="cat-item-20">Parent Category 6</li>
    <li class="cat-item-21">Parent Category 7
        <ul class="children">
            <li>Child Category 1</li>
            <li>Child Category 2</li>
            <li>Child Category 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If you have access to javascript, you can use method `forEach()`, checking for a child element.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("ul:not(.children) > li").forEach((li_has_ul) => {
    if (!li_has_ul.children.length) li_has_ul.style.display = "none";
});
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="cat-item-15">Parent Category 1</li>
    <li class="cat-item-16">Parent Category 2</li>
    <li class="cat-item-17">Parent Category 3
        <ul class="children">
            <li>Child Category 1</li>
            <li>Child Category 2</li>
            <li>Child Category 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item-18">Parent Category 4</li>
    <li class="cat-item-19">Parent Category 5</li>
    <li class="cat-item-20">Parent Category 6</li>
    <li class="cat-item-21">Parent Category 7
        <ul class="children">
            <li>Child Category 1</li>
            <li>Child Category 2</li>
            <li>Child Category 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```